How to execute a bash script in crontab?
I am trying to send 2 csv files from one Pi to another Pi.
I have a shell script that does this and works perfectly fine when executed in the terminal. But it won't work when I run the script in crontab.
what I type to run in the terminal:
bash fileTX.sh

and this transmits to the other Pi perfectly!!
bash script to transmit the files:
#!/bin/bash

password="mypassword"
username="myusername"

ip="111.11.11.11"

while :
do
   sshpass -p "$password" scp /home/pi/csv1.csv $username@$ip:/home/pi/Desktop
   sshpass -p "$password" scp /home/pi/csv2.csv $username@$ip:/home/pi/Desktop
   echo "Files Transmitted!!"
   sleep 30
done

again, in the terminal this works! in crontab it doesn't work
in crontab:
@reboot /home/pi/fileTX.sh &

Please does anyone see what the issue is?!
Ive tried
Made the shell script an executable, gave the full paths for everything, have tried a bunch of prefix variations in crontab like "sh" and "bash" and "/bin/bash" before the path to the script

Linux: Tasks of the crontab file edited by 'sudo crontab -e' run as root. Assume there the environment is not see accordingly.

See the crontab info page for common issues. Good luck.

Please [edit] your question to describe what actually happens when you reboot. Does cron run the script? Does the script produce errors? What do the errors say?

Hi all so i figured this out and I hope this helps anyone who is trying to do the same thing!
I read the output log from crontab and it was a known host issue.
So I found out how to embed the disabling of host check while in the shell script.
So in fileTX.sh:
#!/bin/bash

password="mypassword"
username="myusername"
ip="111.11.11.11"

while :
do
   sshpass -p "$password" scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -r /home/pi/csv1.csv $username@$ip:/home/pi/Desktop
   sshpass -p "$password" scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -r /home/pi/csv2.csv $username@$ip:/home/pi/Desktop
   echo "Files Transmitted!!"
   sleep 30
done

and in crontab, I did
@reboot /bin/bash /home/pi/fileTX.sh &

and this works now!! Rejoice!!!

Link to the page that had the host key disable that worked: https://serverfault.com/questions/330503/scp-without-known-hosts-check

You might try changing the cron entry to
@reboot /bin/bash /home/pi/fileTX.sh &

just to be sure you are using bash to execute.

Tried that, still no go
